# How to modify LSTM calculating?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

When we use Lstm
normal equation is

Z = W1 × x1 + b

Z = np.dot(W × x) + b

can i modify this to

Z = (np.dot(W1 × x1)) × (np.dot(W2 × x2) + b)

I want to use this equation in tensorflow or keras, but i can't find how to do it.

Comment: You may use Lambda layer for this in keras: https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/

Comment: I know you're asking this for keras, but I suggest you to use pytorch since it's more customizable